# Call function in function in other function in angular2 typeScript

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have code

```
  constructor(private heroService :HeroService) {} 

  getHeroes(){
      this.heroService.getHeroes().then(response => this.heroes =response);
  }

  addHero(hero :Hero)  {
      this.heroService.create(hero).then(function(response){
      //call getHeroes here
  });
}
```

How can I call getHeroes marked position.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the passed function to `this` so that the scope is saved:

```
constructor(private heroService :HeroService) {} 

getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(response => this.heroes = response);
}

addHero(hero :Hero) {
    this.heroService.create(hero).then(function(response) {
        this.getHeroes();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which saves the scope of this:

```
addHero(hero :Hero) {
    this.heroService.create(hero).then(response => {
        this.getHeroes();
    });
}
```

But `getHeroes` is async, so if you want to wait for it you'll need to do:

```
constructor(private heroService :HeroService) {} 

getHeroes() {
    return this.heroService.getHeroes().then(response => this.heroes = response);
}

addHero(hero :Hero) {
    this.heroService.create(hero).then(response => {
        this.getHeroes().then(() => {
            // do what ever
        };
    });
}
```